# How do I replace or repair a motion sensor PIR lens?

Tags: lighting, motion-sensor

The PIR lens/translucent cover for my motion sensor for my outdoor light kit broke.  Crumbled to the touch after about a year outside despite being made for outdoors.

The sensor is now way too sensitive without it, but the sensor does still work.

Is it possible to replace this PIR lens, or do I have to throw the baby out with the bathwater and replace the whole sensor piece?

I am not asking where I can buy this part (and I am reaching out to the manufacturer now that I have the part name); I just want to know whether it is possible (and worth my time)  to replace this part or the whole item.

Alternately, can I repair it?  Is there some sort of frosted tape I can use here?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I actually used a piece of a milk container and it works.

Comment: @Ecnerwal My thoughts on "Canonical" (which I know is a bit controversial in general) is not that it should be used on any post that can be a duplicate target but rather that it be used for selective posts that answer frequently asked questions ("how do I install a subpanel?") and/or provide an in-depth comprehensive answer(s) to specific topics ("EV charging sizing and load sharing"), etc. While this particular post is a very good duplicate target for a recent question, it isn't exactly a big, complex or frequently asked type of question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The item you are looking for is a PIR lens.  These are typically sold in bulk, but now that you know the name of it, you should be able to google for one to purchase.

An example one is [here](https://www.distrelec.biz/en/fresnel-lenses-for-pir-sensors-polyethylene-natural-white-20-60-murata-ppgi0902/p/17321465?q=*&filter_Buyable=1&filter_Category3=Fresnel+Lenses+for+PIR+Sensors&page=7&origPos=7&origPageSize=25&simi=97.6)

Comment: Will search, thanks.  Would never have known the name.  Wondering if there are alternatives like using a translucent tape.

Comment: Have reached out to manufacturer Maximus/Jiawei for replacement PIR lens.

Answer (score 3):

I cut a piece to size out of one of those plastic milk containers and it works just as well.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Those PIR lenses are designed to focus different areas of the view onto different areas of the detector; I'm pretty sure a milk jug doesn't have the necessary properties.

Comment: I find this a very simple solution that fixed my $20 outdoor light

Answer (score 2):

I reached out to manufacturer Maximus/Jiawei for a replacement PIR lens. They are sending me one free of charge as a one-time replacement.  I have selected the answer that identified the part for me as that was the major part of my original question.

I will be following this up with "how do I pretreat a PIR lens from crumbling due to outdoor exposure".

Answer (score 1):

Worse comes to worst, the sensor component can be purchased, as they are pretty standard and screw into a "1/2" trade size" thread.  I pay about $20 for a quality Lutron/Eaton, of course there are Cheese cheapies.

Comment: Yeah, but that's about the cost to replace the whole thing (sans lights) and I want to see if I can avoid tossing out "working" parts.